# Scraping tables from stats.nba.com - multiple approaches not working

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

We are trying to scrape the table from here - https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/advanced/?sort=W&dir=-1&Season=2020-21&SeasonType=Regular%20Season - into R. Here's what we've tried so far:

```
# get request from API found in network tab - this doesn't work, the request hangs
httr::GET(url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Advanced&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2020-21&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=')
```

```
# rvest returns empty nodeset when grabbing tables on page
'https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/advanced/?sort=W&dir=-1&Season=2020-21&SeasonType=Regular%20Season' %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('table')
```

Is it possible to scrape the main table from this webpage using R?

Edit:

```
headers = c(
    `authority` = 'www.nba.com',
    `cache-control` = 'max-age=0',
    `sec-ch-ua` = '"Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    `sec-ch-ua-mobile` = '?0',
    `sec-ch-ua-platform` = '"macOS"',
    `upgrade-insecure-requests` = '1',
    `user-agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36',
    `accept` = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    `sec-fetch-site` = 'same-origin',
    `sec-fetch-mode` = 'navigate',
    `sec-fetch-user` = '?1',
    `sec-fetch-dest` = 'document',
    `accept-language` = 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    `cookie` = 'usprivacy=1YNN; AMCVS_248F210755B762187F000101%40AdobeOrg=1; s_ecid=MCMID%7C39761269548384710744541812242089157146; countryCode=US; s_cc=true; ug=61647d1f0252400a3f87470014d69025; nlhidescores=false; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=3524755945110770; qoscid=524912006.1633975588; qossid=1633975588; client_type=html5; client_version=4.4.0; ugs=1; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2021-10-12T23:20:24.183Z; at_check=true; _parsely_visitor={%22id%22:%22pid=0cb0a9a5854f45ea8a6d48f74f03e800%22%2C%22session_count%22:1%2C%22last_session_ts%22:1634155541257}; ab.storage.deviceId.cf150dab-3153-49b0-b48c-66a7c18688ea=%7B%22g%22%3A%2228d2f640-2ad0-b8e9-b78c-016ba5a85671%22%2C%22c%22%3A1634155541318%2C%22l%22%3A1634155541318%7D; OptanonControl=ccc=US&csc=&cic=0&otvers=6.24.0&pctm=2021-10-12T23%3A20%3A24.183Z&reg=ccpa&ustcs=1YNN&vers=3.1.5; aam_uuid=39724801183369993254542124123886279717; s_ips=796; mbox=session#70d31bd3ea124acc80cb089a5594528e#1634158760|PC#70d31bd3ea124acc80cb089a5594528e.34_0#1697401700; ab.storage.sessionId.cf150dab-3153-49b0-b48c-66a7c18688ea=%7B%22g%22%3A%228dcfd2a2-4419-87f9-7e1c-22cf76830e7e%22%2C%22e%22%3A1634158700129%2C%22c%22%3A1634155541315%2C%22l%22%3A1634156900129%7D; s_tp=2924; s_ppv=nba%253Ateams%253Amain%2C27%2C27%2C796%2C1%2C3; ak_bmsc=2C1E9B2928FD1C90ECFF4A5887776269~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQrL4cuDCzpVJ8AQAAytvzew1NuriisqR0MtOqexD1CqvqIJKuuhJda9NNGXOBCOjAdMEXnQjL10fYxWYj9HLm2DJdQLQIjLSqvl3faGyPbxWARg6dKwmf4NK/+RENdJTZfsKGTbwUMxTtPRSoR7TmMc3UWE4tAdft14nRiSPZwp/DJjK9NUhLtpTDjCa65HELyeJ7O4M4d98rAu5R7YYZOEVRjz5VRQEGaFBc5u2OlaUpcyFDqUM+j+jII/6xmqgwVRUhX8t8oNmdeiYpfEALo1yewznqZcfOO18htGp4sF3SLPG8bBFvLeGwW118Mu1rVkyeO4PEvC7UFZUc+a7tGNSjGyGe0WSC/0iSjTC+/ikP2BPwMosXe7DxWk/a0vuFtUlw7jArB/YQuYHH61uu8E97UTA=; AMCV_248F210755B762187F000101%40AdobeOrg=359503849%7CMCMID%7C39761269548384710744541812242089157146%7CMCAAMLH-1634771953%7C7%7CMCAAMB-1634771953%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1634174353s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C5.0.1%7CMCIDTS%7C18914; s_gpv_pageModal=nba%3Astats%3Ateams%3Aadvanced; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; akavpau_allowednbamain=1634169266~id=4fd4cabce5336e66bef275d5dd409a10; bm_sv=467DB2784E3DE76FAA9F4CD21DD7DE3C~8bPs2wRiWvWAD8K8MYos9duNZqYto/EQc8HFibswczdPYqofRTJZOTE4Xy1RsB9fJag8YMdv3OOHkVFDGoh7aG8x4Y8eZepOfBGMFtPmQF0Vgg0XNix35HHU2sk9RKCEQujy2BRS4m269Y6fIapqEQ==; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Wed+Oct+13+2021+19%3A44%3A27+GMT-0400+(Eastern+Daylight+Time)&version=6.24.0&hosts=&consentId=e8a9be54-a345-44df-90e1-eaaf56d98079&interactionCount=2&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=BG30%3A1%2Cven%3A1%2Cpad%3A1%2Cpap%3A1%2Ccad%3A1%2Cmap%3A1%2Cdsa%3A1%2CNBAad%3A1%2Creq%3A1%2Csec%3A1%2Cgld%3A1%2Cpcp%3A1%2Cmcp%3A1%2Cmra%3A1%2Ctdc%3A1%2Ccos%3A1%2Cdid%3A1%2Csid%3A1%2Cpdd%3A1%2Cpcd%3A1%2CNBAmt%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false&geolocation=US%3B'
  )
  
  params = list(
    `sort` = 'W',
    `dir` = '-1',
    `Season` = '2020-21',
    `SeasonType` = 'Regular Season'
  )
  
res <- httr::GET(url = 'https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/advanced/', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), query = params)
```

The following returns a `res` variable but we are now struggling to extract the content from `res`.

Comment: `https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Advanced&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2020-21&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=`

Comment: Data dynamically pulled from there. You should inspect that endpoint in the web traffic and see if endpoint public, which elements of GET are needed. Looks like a fair amount of the querystring could probably be removed.

Comment: I try to make a GET request from that endpoint, however with no success

Comment: Did you try with httr and with headers partic UA and referer?

Comment: yes httr is the library I'm using for GET requests. I have not passed any headers though

Comment: From the line in the "Network" tab where you found the "stats.nba.com..." link.  Right-click and copy as cURL.  Paste to https://curl.trillworks.com/#r and it will build the code with the headers for you.

Comment: that is great. I had no idea so many headers were needed here.

Comment: I am however struggling to get the data from the response object httr::content(res) where `res` is the output from the R code provided at your link

Comment: You probably don't need all those headers, nor all those querystring params. Investigate what you can remove, as copying the curl from browser is almost certainly going to be more verbose than is actually needed.

Comment: Good to know that I can remove some headers, I will test each one. See edit, it is not clear how to get the data from the `res` object. httr::content(res) does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, many of the headers and parameters are not needed, but this works:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

headers = c(
  `Connection` = 'keep-alive',
  `Accept` = 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  `x-nba-stats-token` = 'true',
  `DNT` = '1',
  `User-Agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36',
  `x-nba-stats-origin` = 'stats',
  `Sec-GPC` = '1',
  `Origin` = 'https://www.nba.com',
  `Sec-Fetch-Site` = 'same-site',
  `Sec-Fetch-Mode` = 'cors',
  `Sec-Fetch-Dest` = 'empty',
  `Referer` = 'https://www.nba.com/',
  `Accept-Language` = 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  `If-Modified-Since` = 'Wed, 13 Oct 2021 23:24:06 GMT'
)

params = list(
  `Conference` = '',
  `DateFrom` = '',
  `DateTo` = '',
  `Division` = '',
  `GameScope` = '',
  `GameSegment` = '',
  `LastNGames` = '0',
  `LeagueID` = '00',
  `Location` = '',
  `MeasureType` = 'Advanced',
  `Month` = '0',
  `OpponentTeamID` = '0',
  `Outcome` = '',
  `PORound` = '0',
  `PaceAdjust` = 'N',
  `PerMode` = 'PerGame',
  `Period` = '0',
  `PlayerExperience` = '',
  `PlayerPosition` = '',
  `PlusMinus` = 'N',
  `Rank` = 'N',
  `Season` = '2020-21',
  `SeasonSegment` = '',
  `SeasonType` = 'Regular Season',
  `ShotClockRange` = '',
  `StarterBench` = '',
  `TeamID` = '0',
  `TwoWay` = '0',
  `VsConference` = '',
  `VsDivision` = ''
)

res <- httr::GET(url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), query = params)
data <- httr::content(res) %>% .[['resultSets']] %>% .[[1]]
column_names <- data$headers %>% as.character()  
dt <- rbindlist(data$rowSet) %>% setnames(column_names)
```

Gives:

```
head(dt, 2)
      TEAM_ID      TEAM_NAME GP  W  L W_PCT  MIN E_OFF_RATING OFF_RATING E_DEF_RATING DEF_RATING E_NET_RATING NET_RATING AST_PCT
1: 1610612737  Atlanta Hawks 72 41 31 0.569 3481          113      114.3        110.6      112.1          2.5        2.2   0.591
2: 1610612738 Boston Celtics 72 36 36   0.5 3476          111      113.1          110      111.8          0.9        1.2   0.566
   AST_TO AST_RATIO OREB_PCT DREB_PCT REB_PCT TM_TOV_PCT EFG_PCT TS_PCT E_PACE  PACE PACE_PER40 POSS   PIE GP_RANK W_RANK L_RANK
1:   1.82      17.6    0.284    0.742   0.516      0.133   0.539  0.581   99.9 98.68      82.23 7160 0.511       1     11     11
2:   1.67      17.1    0.289    0.737    0.51      0.141   0.543  0.574  100.7 98.94      82.45 7172 0.501       1     16     16
   W_PCT_RANK MIN_RANK OFF_RATING_RANK DEF_RATING_RANK NET_RATING_RANK AST_PCT_RANK AST_TO_RANK AST_RATIO_RANK OREB_PCT_RANK
1:         11       11               9              18              11           18          14             20             6
2:         16       16              10              13              13           27          22             26             3
   DREB_PCT_RANK REB_PCT_RANK TM_TOV_PCT_RANK EFG_PCT_RANK TS_PCT_RANK PACE_RANK PIE_RANK CFID       CFPARAMS
1:             9            7              10           16          10        22       10   10  Atlanta Hawks
2:            13           10              18           12          16        20       17   10 Boston Celtics
```

Comment: This is fantastic. I was selecting `copy all as cURL` instead of `copy as cURL` on accident, which is why the code in my question does not match code here in your solution

Comment: every column returned is of type list, which does seem problematic, but this I think I can resolve

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that.  I haven't used purrr::transpose before.   Add `dt[, (column_names) := lapply(.SD, unlist)]`

Answer (score 1):

A `RSelenium` solution,

```
library(RSelenium)
library(dply)
library(rvest)

driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")
remDr<-driver[["client"]]


remDr$navigate('https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/advanced/?sort=W&dir=-1&Season=2020-21&SeasonType=Regular%20Season')
# select element
table <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/nba-stat-table/div[2]/div[1]/table')


df1 = table$getPageSource()[[1]]%>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_table()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 30 x 39
      `` TEAM         GP     W     L   MIN OffRtg DefRtg NetRtg `AST%` `AST/TO` ASTRatio `OREB%` `DREB%` `REB%` `TOV%` `eFG%` `TS%`  PACE   PIE POSS  `GP RANK`
   <int> <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <lgl>    
 1     1 Utah Jazz    72    52    20  3471   116.   108.    9     57.3     1.66     17.3    28.4    75.7   52.9   14.2   56.3  59.7  99.4  54.2 7,193 NA       
 2     2 Phoenix ~    72    51    21  3496   116.   110.    5.9   62.2     2.15     19.6    24.8    74.1   50     12.6   56.4  59.7  98    53.4 7,137 NA       
 3     3 Philadel~    72    49    23  3486   112.   107     5.5   57.2     1.64     17.2    27.7    73.7   51.1   14.3   54.1  57.9 100.   53.6 7,272 NA       
 4     4 Brooklyn~    72    48    24  3481   117.   113.    4.2   62.1     1.98     19.3    25.2    72.6   50.3   13.4   57.5  61   100.   53.2 7,280 NA       
 5     5 Denver N~    72    47    25  3496   116.   112.    4.8   62.1     1.99     19.3    29.2    75.1   52.2   13.6   55.7  58.8  97.7  52.5 7,123 NA       
 6     5 LA Clipp~    72    47    25  3456   117.   111.    6.1   58.4     1.85     18.1    27      75.4   51.8   13.5   56.4  59.9  97.6  53   7,036 NA       
 7     7 Milwauke~    72    46    26  3466   116.   111.    5.8   56.9     1.84     18      26.9    75.5   51.9   13.4   56.6  59.3 103.   53.3 7,423 NA       
 8     8 Dallas M~    72    42    30  3461   115.   112.    2.3   55.7     1.9      17.2    25.3    73.4   49.6   12.3   55    58.2  97.9  51   7,062 NA       
 9     8 Los Ange~    72    42    30  3491   110.   107.    2.9   60.7     1.62     18      26.9    74.8   51.1   15.2   53.6  56.9  98.8  51.7 7,184 NA
```

Or using `XML`

```
readHTMLTable((table$getPageSource()[[1]]))
```